# Save HTML from php

Tags: php, html

Let's say I want to use php to generate dynamic data on my website, but I don't want users to go to any `.php` page.

Rather, I'd like to run the php scripts once each night and save a `.html` file so that when browsing my website users just see static html.

The way I'm picturing this is that for every page that needs dynamic data, there is a .html and a .php for it.  For example:

- newsAndInformation.html
- newsAndInformation.php

Is this common practice? Are there good tutorials out there for things like this?

Comment: You can edit `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thats called static caching. You can use ob_start and ob_get_contents to get your generated code and put it into a static file. You could use a htaccess to check if there is a static file, and serve the static file if it is there and younger than xx days.. this is just a simple example.

Comment: Is this because you want to cache something or just because you want to make it look like an html page?
Because with url-rewriting, you could make the url `/anypage.html`
point to `anypage.php` without anyone ever realize it.

Comment: I'm interested in doing this for caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [speed up your site with static pages](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201303/Blog/Speed-Up-Dynamic-Websites-With-Static-Pages/) by using a clever mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Example/ index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

This rule does the following...

1. Checks that a file doesn't already exist for the requested URL
2. Checks that a directory doesn't already exist for the requested URL
3. If YES - shows the static file / directory (directory would need an index.html file)
4. If NO - redirects to your PHP file, which can run and then save the appropriate file for the next request

Your PHP file would spit out the response:

```
<?php
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On');

ob_start();

// Logic to create your content...

// use ob_get_contents() to get the response and save it

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

A rough example would be...

```
yoursite/Example/Test/
```

On the first visit, this would hit your PHP page. You would then save the file to `/Example/Test/index.html` and the second request would serve the static page without using PHP.

Comment: +1 Nice! You would need to add something like a cron job to clean out the html files once a day to meet the OP's refresh requirement.

Comment: I normally delete the folder automatically when I edit the page, so it will only regenerate the static file if I have actually made a change. For pages that need to be genuinely dynamic (i.e. automatic publishing based on future dates) I handle the cache with a smaller PHP file that checks the date and time of the cached item.

Comment: Just found out that my Yahoo Small Business hosting does not allow me to upload my own .htaccess file.  Womp womp.  I'm changing hosts soon enough, so I'll try this then.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple class that uses [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to do this.

If you have enough data that requires a more complex solution, you could find a more extensive cache system.

Answer (score 0):

add the following in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

This will make `http://www.domain.com/myPage.html` really point to `http://www.domain.com/myPage.php` but the users see the `.html`